# insertRule() not inserting rule but not giving any errors

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodes

I am trying to insert a style rule directly into the head of a document.

It inserts the style element but not the code itself. No errors or anything.

```
var thumbStyles = document.createElement("style"); 
    document.head.appendChild(thumbStyles);
    thumbStyles.sheet.insertRule(
    "figure#styleThumbs { \
    position: absolute; \
    left: 0px; \
    bottom: 0px; \
    } \
    ")
    thumbStyles.sheet.insertRule(
    "figure#styleThumbs img { \
    outline: 1px solid black; \
    cursor: pointer; \
    opacity: 0.75; \
    } \
    ")
    thumbStyles.sheet.insertRule(
    "figure#styleThumbs img:hover { \
    outline: 1px solid red; \
    opacity: 1.0; \
    } \
    ");
```

[Picture of HTML Head with style but no style code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDZQd.png)

[I also asked this question on FCC but have no answers](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/insertrule-causing-uncaught-domexception-error/414274/5)

Comment: why you want to add this style to the head using JS?

Comment: Its supposed to teach us about Nodes and this was apart of the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inserted CSS is not displayed in the DOM, but it does work.

```js
var thumbStyles = document.createElement("style"); 
document.head.appendChild(thumbStyles);
thumbStyles.sheet.insertRule(`#test{
background-color: dodgerblue;
}`);
```

```html
<div id="test">
This is a test
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The second I changed from using quotes to backticks it works